# Image dimensions metadata on google-cloud-storage.

Tags: image, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I need to know the dimensions of images I'm saving, so that I can add them to the  `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` meta tags for image previewing by Facebook, Twitter etc - [as is suggested by this Facebook documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images)

If I'm saving these images to a google storage bucket - is there any already existing way of finding these images sizes with existing standard metadata, or will I need to add some custom metadata [as described in this google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata?hl=en_US#custom-metadata)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that Cloud Storage sees everything as [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations), it does not have multiple object definitions, depending on the type of the object (like media, text... it does something like this via `Content-Type` but it's [not what you're looking for](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#content-type)). In this sense, there are no object type characteristic-metadata (i.e. width and height of images or length for sounds or videos).

The only predefined (or how you call it, *standard*) metadata entries are the ones mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#editable) and, yes, as you specified, you need to add [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-metadata).