# get image size before download

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloudflare, cloudinary

I use Potoswipe in my project. Potoswipe requires the definition of the images size. In a time when I used PHP that was a simple, nowadays in the serverless time it looks like an issue.

How can I get an image size on a client? I’ve checked few cloud storages providers they all are offering resizing but it is not exactly what I’m looking for, I need a full image property before upload image when I initialize the App.

Comment: What do you need to know that isn't covered in the Photoswipe FAQ? http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html -- it provides sample code for getting image size from a short HEAD, or advises you to use your cloud hosting API.

Comment: If you are using Google Cloud Storage, have a look at this SO post that explains how Cloud Storage views objects and what metadata can be provided - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323461/image-dimensions-metadata-on-google-cloud-storage

Comment: I've seen the Photoswipe FAQ. Honestly, it anyway requires pre-downloading of images. I also use Vue in the project that took some work to connect the Photoswipe already. So the only way the custom metadata or keep sizes in a database?

Comment: So my solution is using this library https://github.com/image-size/image-size

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to find a hosting service with an API that provides the metadata you need.

Failing that, you can work out the dimensions of an image by looking at just the first few dozen bytes. All modern image formats contain dimensions in a file header. Examples in three languages are linked to in the `[Photoswipe FAQ][1]`.

So, you need to download enough bytes (this varies per file format). To do this you need to use the `Range` header in the HTTP request. For example:

```
curl http://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg -i -H "Range: bytes=0-1023"
```

... will get the first kilobyte of that image. Whatever HTTP client you use, it will have a way to set a request header.

Comment: Thank you that looks promising.